# Catch block in constructor without try

Tags: c++, exception, constructor

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int foo()
{
    throw 1;
}

struct A {
    int a;
    public:
    A() try : a(foo())
    {
        cout << "Constructor A\n";
    } catch(...)
    {
        cout << "Catched in A\n";
    }
};

struct B : A {
    B()
    {
        cout << "Constructor B\n";
        ::foo();
    } catch(...)
    {
        cout << "Catched in B\n";
    }
    void foo()
    {
        
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        cout << "Catched in foo\n";
    }
};

int main () try
{
    B b;
    return 0;
} catch (...)
{
    cout << "Catched in main\n";
}
```

It outputs:

> Catched in A
>
> Catched in main

Why B's catch block doesn't catch anything? And how can it exist withouth try?

Clang only detects error on line 26:
`error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers` and thinks that `B::foo`'s block is OK. I'm confused :)

Clang++ v 3.4

gcc v 4.8

Comment: The order of the constructor calls are A->B. So if there's an error in A, the constructor call of B won't be thrown (Or called at all)

Comment: @NoamRodrik `A`'s constructor catches all exceptions, so it is safe and `B`'s ctor must be called. I've tried making `B` class independent from `A` (removing inheritance) and the result is : `Constructor B \n Catched in main`

Comment: @yanpas: "A's constructor catches all exceptions". Yes, but the magic constructor-catch block has an implicit `throw;` at the end. It _cannot_ swallow exceptions, they will _always_ trickle out.

Comment: @yanpas The right syntax for to catch exceptions from `foo()` using the lesser-known function-try syntax would be `void foo() try { /* stuff */ } catch { /* things */ }`. Why `g++` seems to accept the hanging `catch` block without a `try` is being discussed (possibly somewhat redundantly) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38415131 and to me looks like a loophole in its parsing that should be reported to the GCC Bugzilla.