# catch without try compiling successfully

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The following code compiles successfully with g++ version 5.1.0.  Notice the `catch` without a corresponding `try` in the member function `foo::bar()`.  I was wondering if this syntax was legal and if so what effect it had?

```
struct foo
{
  void bar()
  {
  }
  catch (...)
  {
  }
};

int main ()
{
  foo f;
  f.bar();
  return 0;
}
```

Originally seen in [Catch block in constructor without try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38414951/catch-block-in-constructor-without-try)

Comment: Er... I really don't see what you're asking here that won't already be covered in an answer to the original question you link to.

Comment: @hvd There's no answer to the original question only comments visible to me. And no discussion or answer to why the syntax allows `catch` without a corresponding `try`

Comment: Yes, "won't" refers to the future. The question isn't answered yet. I don't see how the question is answerable without also including what you're asking here.

Comment: @hvd: constructors are special, the other question is about the special contructor catch.  This question appears to be about general functions, which isn't allowed IIRC.

Comment: @MooingDuck A function can have a try-catch as its definition just like a constructor can, it's just that there is very little reason to use that syntax outside of a constructor definition. When the `try` keyword is included, anyway. But if the other question asks whether it's valid without the `try` keyword in a constructor definition, and this question asks whether it's valid without the `try` keyword outside a constructor definition, fair enough, that's a good enough difference for asking a separate question.

Comment: Doesn't compile with clang 3.8.0. I don't even know how gcc compiles this as I'm glancing the standard syntax. http://eel.is/c++draft/except#1

Comment: I can only guess this is a loophole in `g++`'s parsing whereby the `catch` doesn't require a corresponding function-scope `try`, even though it's completely useless without one, and (for the same reason) the Standard definitely seems to require the two. If so, I would definitely suggest that you submit this to their Bugzilla: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla

Comment: [sighs theatrically] OK, I'll do it: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71909

Comment: @underscore_d thank you

Comment: @RichardCritten no problem - thanks to you for bringing it up in the first place!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The example you give,

```
struct foo
{
  void bar()
  {
  }
  catch (...)
  {
  }
};
```

… is not valid standard C++.

It might be a g++ language extension.

The `catch`es in the question you linked to look like *function catch blocks*, except that also that requires a `try` keyword.

Comment: fwiw, compiles for me with `g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`, which i would've _hoped_ would turn off all silly proprietary extensions

Comment: `g++` allows other stuff to be defined between `bar()` and the `catch` too, without generating any syntax errors or warnings, but of course, the `catch` doesn't actually catch anything without a `try`, and _then_ it must be right below the function whose scope is enclosed by said `try`. I'm guessing this is a loophole in its parsing where the `catch` doesn't require a corresponding function-scope `try`

Answer (score 5):

As others were quick to point out, the quoted code is not well-formed C++. It was allowed through due to an oversight in the rewritten C++ parser that's used in recent GCC 4/5/6 branches.

I filed this as [GCC Bug/PR c++/71909](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71909). As can be seen there, commits have just been made to all 3 branches, to ensure that a function-`catch` block will only be accepted if a matching function-`try` block has already been encountered. A 3-day turnaround, that's pretty good :-)

Thanks to **Richard** for bringing this up!